# Get selected dropdown Meteor with many many elements with same class

Tags: jquery, meteor, drop-down-menu

I have a Meteor project that has 20 dropdown selects each having a unique set of dropdown options. All the selects have the same class of: class="browser-default tablesassignments":

```
<template name="placecardsnot">
{{#each placecardnotassigned}}
<select class="browser-default tablesassignments" id="{{_id}}">
<option value="">Assign Table</option>
{{> tablenotassigned }}
</select>
{{/each}}   
</template>
```

The dropdown options come from another Meteor Collection and looks like this:

```
<template name="tablenotassigned">
{{#each table}}
<option class="optionvalue" value="{{_id}}">{{number}} - {{description}}</option>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can get three values when a dropdown changes. I need the ID of the select, the id of the selected dropdown option (which comes from the second template) and the text value of the selected dropdown option.

I can't seem to get the Jquery and Meteor integration right and would appreciate any help.

In terms of template.helpers everthing is loading fine, I just can't seem to get the values so I can update the correct collection with the selected dropdown choice.

The code I'm working with now and I've tried many variations:

```
Template.placecardsnot.events({
'change .tablesassignments': function(event){
     var value = $(this).val();
     console.log(value);
    $('.tablesassignments').each(function(){
    $(this).val(value);
    console.log(value); //
    });
}
});
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if your collection is attached to your parent template, try accessing it using  `Template.parentData()`. Just log it and look if this is what you need.

Comment: The second collection is not really attached to the parent, its just the dropdown choices come from the parent template. Does that mean it won't work?

Comment: try it! It doesn't cost much. In your dropbox template, log the `Template.parentData()` and look if the data you are looking for are there. If they are, you are not passing it in your code. This would be the problem.

Comment: You have two data contexts, the current *placecardnotassigned* at the parent level and the current *table* element in your dropdown. @Billybobbonnet is right about getting the parent context. *this* in your event handler has the information about the value *.val()* and text *.text()* of the selected dropdown.

Comment: @Billybobbonnet When I do 'var parent_data = Template.parentData();
console.log(parent_data);'  I do get an object returned in the console. I can't find in the documentation how do I now access the ID from the parent? Also, all the selects are the same class so without using "$this" how can I get the value of the selected option?